How to Upload JSON Keys to the "metadata" Attribute in the LangChain JSONLoader Using JQ Package?
The primary objective of this activity is to display a summarized response alongside the document source in the LangChain QA bot.
Within my input JSON data, there are three keys: page_name, page_data, and page_url. I aim to save the content under page_data in the page_content attribute of LangChain's Document class using jq package. Additionally, I intend to store page_name and page_url in the metadata. Could you guide me on how to accomplish this?
    from langchain_community.document_loaders import JSONLoader

    ### data exported from MongoDB database

    json_data = 
    [
      {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "65ed5d18b251090135c27d98"
        },
        "page_name": "Homepage",
        "page_data": "Content about homepage",
        "page_url": "https://mywebsite.com/homepage"
      },
      {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "65ed5d2fb251090135c27d99"
        },
        "page_name": "Contact US",
        "page_data": "Content about Contact US",
        "page_url": "https://mywebsite.com/contactus"
      }
    ]

    ### LangChain JSON loader Class

    loader = JSONLoader(
        file_path="/content/web_data.json",
        jq_schema='.[].page_data',
        text_content=False)
    
    docs = loader.load()

    print(docs) -->

    [Document(page_content="Content about homepage", metadata={'source': '/content/json_data.json', 'seq_num': 1}),
     Document(page_content="Content about Contact US", metadata={'source': '/content/json_data.json', 'seq_num': 2})]

Final docs should look like this :
[Document(page_content="Content about homepage", metadata={'source': '/content/json_data.json', 'seq_num': 1, 'page_name': 'Homepage',"page_url": "https://mywebsite.com/homepage"}),
 Document(page_content="Content about Contact US", metadata={'source': '/content/json_data.json', 'seq_num': 2,"page_name": "Contact US","page_url": "https://mywebsite.com/contactus"})]


I think the following jq program will generate your desired output format. I had to make a few assumptions, because source is nowhere to be found in your input and your output doc is not valid JSON.
to_entries | map({
    page_content: .value.page_data,
    metadata: (.value | {
        source: "/content/json_data.json",
        page_name,
        page_url
    } + {seq_num:(.key+1)})
})

or
to_entries | map((.value | {
    page_content: .page_data,
    metadata: {
        source: "/content/json_data.json",
        page_name,
        page_url
    }
}) * { metadata: { seq_num: (.key+1) } })

Output:
[
  {
    "page_content": "Content about homepage",
    "metadata": {
      "source": "/content/json_data.json",
      "page_name": "Homepage",
      "page_url": "https://mywebsite.com/homepage",
      "seq_num": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "page_content": "Content about Contact US",
    "metadata": {
      "source": "/content/json_data.json",
      "page_name": "Contact US",
      "page_url": "https://mywebsite.com/contactus",
      "seq_num": 1
    }
  }
]

